# Codeigniter and Form

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have a problem with Codeigniter and my hosting provider...

I have created a form with function form_open('welcome/index') and it produces this html code 
    `<form action="http://gggg.com/index2.php/welcome/index" method="post">` 
but this doesn't work, infact when I submit the form I will return in the same page without effects.

I have to say that there are no errors in the code, because it works in localhost and works also if I write `form_open('http://gggg.com/index2.php/welcome/index')`.

So, in summary if I write:
        `form_open('welcome/index')`, it doesn't work
else if I write:
    `form_open('http://gggg.com/index2.php/welcome/index')`, it works

It's very strange, can anybody help me?

Comment: it seems to be a problem with hosting provider? In this case my hosting is by aruba

Comment: I solved updating to version 2.0

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what URL it is actually sending the form data to.

You need to look through your config file. Make sure the correct values are set for:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://gggg.com/";
$config['index_page'] = "index2.php";
```

Also make sure you htaccess files are correct, if you are running on Apache.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have checked these variables many times and those are corrects. As I said before, it works in localhost...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not [modified your htaccess to allow URLs](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) like http://ggg.com/controller/function/param1, you should always add 'index2.php' and the beginning of all of your URLs.

Try to modify using `form_open('index2.php/welcome/index')`.

Anyways, check your config.php file just how Michael told you.

Comment: I have tried with echo form_open('index2.php/welcome/index'); and it doesn't work beacuse it creates this url: http://www.gggg.com/index2.php/index2.php/welcome/index